# Filter a Mapped value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, parquet

Sorry, very new.

I am using pandas to read parquet. A column in my dataset is mapped. I would to filter based on the mapped value, returning only rows which meet my condition.

My data looks like this:
Columns: [UUID, UUID_c, Rating, approvalTimestamp]
the Rating column looks like this (and is an object datatype):

```
[('US', 'IB'), ('EU', 'IA'), ('CA', 'IIC'), ('CH', 'III'), ('UK', 'IA'), ('AU', 'IB'), ('TW', 'III'), ('TK', 'IV')]
```

I want to filter for US values of either "IA" or "IB".

This returns all instances where "US" is in the map:

```
df2 = df[df['Rating'].str.contains("US")]
```

This returns an empty dataframe:

```
df2 = df[df['Rating'].str.contains("IA")]
```

How to I return the instances where the value assigned to US is "IA" or "IB"?

dataframe looks like:

```
UUID  |  UUID_c  |   Rating   |  approvalTimeStamp|
---------------------------------------------------
037a9db2-c91f-4e93-a36e-3b6e7adb885f   |   ['8b2c409b-6c01-0100-2d32-670000010368','1fdfa790-a001-0100-5efe-b90000060013'] | [('US', 'IB'), ('EU', 'IA'), ('CA', 'IIC'), ('CH', 'III'), ('UK', 'IA'), ('AU', 'IB'), ('TW', 'III'), ('TK', 'IV')]   |   2022-01-06T19:10:46.304734Z
037a9db2-c91f-4e93-a36e-3b6e7adb885f   |   ['8b2c409b-6c01-0100-2d32-670000010368','691aa282-e1ec-4904-b6c3-18a20ba3cda2'] | [('US', 'IIC'), ('EU', 'IA'), ('CA', 'IIC'), ('CH', 'III'), ('UK', 'IA'), ('AU', 'IB'), ('TW', 'III'), ('TK', 'IV')]   |   2022-01-06T19:10:46.304734Z
037a9db2-c91f-4e93-a36e-3b6e7adb885f   |   ['8b2c409b-6c01-0100-2d32-670000010368','eb8d409b-6c01-0100-0f90-bd0000410011'] | [('US', 'IA'), ('EU', 'IA'), ('CA', 'IIC'), ('CH', 'III'), ('UK', 'IA'), ('AU', 'IB'), ('TW', 'III'), ('TK', 'IV')]   |   2022-01-06T19:10:46.304734Z
```

Would like to return this: (fitlered out the US, IIC row)

```
 UUID  |  UUID_c  |   Rating   |  approvalTimeStamp|
    ---------------------------------------------------
    037a9db2-c91f-4e93-a36e-3b6e7adb885f   |   ['8b2c409b-6c01-0100-2d32-670000010368','1fdfa790-a001-0100-5efe-b90000060013'] | [('US', 'IB'), ('EU', 'IA'), ('CA', 'IIC'), ('CH', 'III'), ('UK', 'IA'), ('AU', 'IB'), ('TW', 'III'), ('TK', 'IV')]   |   2022-01-06T19:10:46.304734Z
    037a9db2-c91f-4e93-a36e-3b6e7adb885f   |   ['8b2c409b-6c01-0100-2d32-670000010368','eb8d409b-6c01-0100-0f90-bd0000410011'] | [('US', 'IA'), ('EU', 'IA'), ('CA', 'IIC'), ('CH', 'III'), ('UK', 'IA'), ('AU', 'IB'), ('TW', 'III'), ('TK', 'IV')]   |   2022-01-06T19:10:46.304734Z
```

Comment: It's not clear what the column data format is. I believe you need to supply a short example including the dataframe and the expected output so it is more clear what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['037a9db2-c91f-4e93-a36e-3b6e7adb885f','037a9db2-c91f-4e93-a36e-3b6e7adb885f','037a9db2-c91f-4e93-a36e-3b6e7adb885f'],
                   'Rating' : [[('US', 'IB'), ('EU', 'IA'), ('CA', 'IIC'), ('CH', 'III'), ('UK', 'IA'), ('AU', 'IB'), ('TW', 'III'), ('TK', 'IV')],[('US', 'IIC'), ('EU', 'IA'), ('CA', 'IIC'), ('CH', 'III'), ('UK', 'IA'), ('AU', 'IB'), ('TW', 'III'), ('TK', 'IV')],[('US', 'IA'), ('EU', 'IA'), ('CA', 'IIC'), ('CH', 'III'), ('UK', 'IA'), ('AU', 'IB'), ('TW', 'III'), ('TK', 'IV')]]})
df

    id                                      Rating
0   037a9db2-c91f-4e93-a36e-3b6e7adb885f    [(US, IB), (EU, IA), (CA, IIC), (CH, III), (UK...
1   037a9db2-c91f-4e93-a36e-3b6e7adb885f    [(US, IIC), (EU, IA), (CA, IIC), (CH, III), (U...
2   037a9db2-c91f-4e93-a36e-3b6e7adb885f    [(US, IA), (EU, IA), (CA, IIC), (CH, III), (UK...
```

Lambda function:

```
lst = df.apply(lambda row : True if ('US','IIC') not in row['Rating'] else False, axis= 1)
df[lst]
```

Result

```
    id                                      Rating
0   037a9db2-c91f-4e93-a36e-3b6e7adb885f    [(US, IB), (EU, IA), (CA, IIC), (CH, III), (UK...
2   037a9db2-c91f-4e93-a36e-3b6e7adb885f    [(US, IA), (EU, IA), (CA, IIC), (CH, III), (UK...
```